# Speed sensor location on 03 jetta 2.0 engine

Tags: engine, vehicle-speed-sensor

So i was driving yesterday n the car shut off. I lost acceleration first then the car shut off leaving all my lights on. I pulled over turned it off then tried to turn it back on n i got nothing. No clicks no turn over no nothing. Had it jumped but only lasted a few minutes n the same thing happened. 
Had the same thing happen my in 03 maxima, after replacing alternator and battery multiple times it didnt help the car. So i know its not the same in this car. 
I have three codes that show up .. vehicle speed sensor n an o2 sensor. I was told its the speed sensor.. 
My question is... where is my speed sensor located.

Comment: What were the codes? Do you mean the vehicle speed sensor or the crankshaft position sensor? A VSS won’t cause a car to no start.

Answer (score 1):

Its located on top of the transmission, you may have to remove some parts to get at it

[image]